# How to use getMethod() with primitive types?

Tags: java, reflection

This is the class:

```
class Foo {
  public void bar(int a, Object b) {
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to get "reflect" this method from the class:

```
Class c = Foo.class;
Class[] types = { ... }; // what should be here?
Method m = c.getMethod("bar", types);
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

There's just an `int.class`.

```
Class[] types = { int.class, Object.class };
```

An alternative is [`Integer.TYPE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE).

```
Class[] types = { Integer.TYPE, Object.class };
```

The same applies on other primitives.

Comment: And how do you invoke the method? If I want to pass boolean to such a method it does not work: invoke(null, new Object[] {myString, myBool}); ... boolean cannot be converted to Object.

Comment: @Racky Works for me, at least syntactically. Are you using a Java version below 5 (missing Autoboxing)?

Answer (score 3):

The parameter of the method is a primitive `short` not an Object `Short`.

Reflection will not find the method because you specified an object short.  The parameters in `getMethod()` have to match exactly.

EDIT:
The question was changed.  Initially, the question was to find a method that takes a single primitive short.