# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:

Tags: java, annotations

Please help me to find why exception comes here.

```
public class SampleAnnotation
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {

        Method method = Check.class.getDeclaredMethod("getId", null);
        System.out.println("method:"+method);
        SampleAnnotation1 annotMethd = method.getAnnotation(SampleAnnotation1.class);
        System.out.println(annotMethd.author()+"::"+annotMethd.lastModified());

        method = Check.class.getDeclaredMethod("getId", Integer.class);
        System.out.println("method:"+method);
        annotMethd = method.getAnnotation(SampleAnnotation1.class);
        System.out.println(annotMethd.author()+"::"+annotMethd.lastModified());


    }
}

@Documented
@Retention(value=RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value={ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE,ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.PACKAGE,ElementType.PARAMETER,ElementType.TYPE})
@interface SampleAnnotation1 
    {
           String author();
           String lastModified() default "N/A";        

    }
@SampleAnnotation1
( author = "leo",  
  lastModified = "joe"
  )
class Check
{
    @SampleAnnotation1
    ( 
            author = "joe"          
    )
    public int id;

    @SampleAnnotation1
    ( 
            author = "joeidgetter"
    )
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @SampleAnnotation1
    ( 
            author = "joeidgetterwithint"
    )
    public int getId(int i) {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }       

}
```

**Exception :**

```
method:public int leo.annotate.Check.getId()
joeidgetter::N/A
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: leo.annotate.Check.getId(java.lang.Integer)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
    at leo.annotate.SampleAnnotation.main(SampleAnnotation.java:20)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use getMethod() with primitive types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032833/how-to-use-getmethod-with-primitive-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an `Integer` class parameter.

You need to pass a primitive, as your method takes a primitive `int`.

Use:

```
method = Check.class.getDeclaredMethod("getId", int.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `Integer.class` whereas your method takes a `int` parameter, so you should use `int.class` instead.