# class.getMethod() is not working in my context

Tags: java, methods

I cannot figure out how this part of code always throws NoSuchMethodException. Can anyone help? The Method M... line is probably where the code is erring. Either the method getMethod is broken or I am using it wrong. If you need more of the file just ask. Thanks!

```
floorName = "Base";
try {
        Class[] cArg = new Class[5];
        cArg[0] = World.class;
        cArg[1] = Integer.class;
        cArg[2] = Integer.class;
        cArg[3] = Integer.class;
        cArg[4] = String.class;
        Method m = TowerFloors.class.getMethod("genFloor_" + floorName.toLowerCase(), cArg); //Probable Origin of Throwable Error
        try {
            done = (Boolean) m.invoke(m, x, y, z, color);
            success = done;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            DungeonMod.logger.log(Level.ERROR, "Error in generating tower floor \"" + floorName + "\"(" + e + "), generating \"Base\" floor instead.");
            done = genFloor_base(worldA, x, y, z, color);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        DungeonMod.logger.log(Level.ERROR, "Error in generating tower floor \"" + floorName + "\"(" + e + "), generating \"Base\" floor instead.");
        done = genFloor_base(worldA, x, y, z, color);
    }
```

and here is the method:

```
 public static boolean genFloor_base(World world, int i, int j, int k, String color) {
    if (color.toLowerCase().equals("blue")) {
        //Floor
        BlockFill.fillRectangle(world, i - 10, j, k - 10, i + 10, j, k + 10, TowerDungeonBuildingBlocks.towerDungeonWallBlue);
        //Roof
        BlockFill.fillRectangle(world, i - 10, j + 5, k - 10, i + 10, j + 5, k + 10, TowerDungeonBuildingBlocks.towerDungeonWallBlue);
        //++Wall
        BlockFill.fillRectangle(world, i + 10, j + 1, k + 10, i + 10, j + 4, k - 10, TowerDungeonBuildingBlocks.towerDungeonWallBlue);
        //--Wall
        BlockFill.fillRectangle(world, i - 10, j + 1, k - 10, i - 10, j + 4, k + 10, TowerDungeonBuildingBlocks.towerDungeonWallBlue);
        //+-Wall
        BlockFill.fillRectangle(world, i + 10, j + 1, k - 10, i - 10, j + 4, k - 10, TowerDungeonBuildingBlocks.towerDungeonWallBlue);
        //-+Wall
        BlockFill.fillRectangle(world, i - 10, j + 1, k + 10, i + 10, j + 4, k + 10, TowerDungeonBuildingBlocks.towerDungeonWallBlue);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

(And yes this is a Minecraft mod)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use getMethod() with primitive types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032833/how-to-use-getmethod-with-primitive-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method

```
public static boolean genFloor_base(World world, int i, int j, int k, String color) {
```

has 5 parameters, where `i`, `j`, and `k`, are of type `int`.

You'll want to use

```
int.class
```

instead of

```
Integer.class
```

to identify the parameter type.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Just an Illegal Argument Exception to deal with but that was an easy fix.

Comment: @IonLee If this answer worked for you, it would be courteous of you to click the tick mark next to the answer.  That's your way of signalling to the rest of the Stack Overflow community that you don't need any further answers to this question.

Comment: @DavidWallace Oops I thought I did. Thanks for mentioning!